# Communicating with a REST Web Service via HttpWebRequest manually without custom objects

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, httpwebrequest, linq-to-xml

I have a service (let's call it A) which needs to communicate with a Web Service (let's call it B).  Service A is not a Web Service, and due to certain design decisions won't include a Web Service for this.  The methods I need to interact with in Service B do not take in any custom objects - `List<string>` is the only object involved in one of the calls.  Service B is set up to accept XML.

Here's an example of one of the methods in the interface for Service B:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "AddBasicTocsEvent/id={id}&latitude={lat}&longtitude={long}&someRemarkAboutTheData={sratd}")]
    StatusMessage AddBasicThing(short id, decimal latitude, decimal longtitude, string someRemarkAboutTheData);
```

How would I go about structuring the XML to send so that Service B can extract the data and toss in the correct values to the specified parameters?

This is what I'm thinking Service A should do (uses a utilities class that handles sending an HttpWebRequest - this has been tested and works):

```
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
    XElement root = new XElement("content");

    root.Add(new XElement("id", 42));
    root.Add(new XElement("latitude", 42.42m));
    root.Add(new XElement("longitude", 42.42m));
    root.Add(new XElement("someRemarkAboutTheData", "They're Grrrreat!"));

    xDoc.Add(root);

    HttpStringResponse = UtilsClass.PerformHttpPost(THE_URL_FOR_POSTING, xDoc.ToString());
```

Is this headed in the right direction (and hopefully mostly complete)?  Or is this totally bonkers and demanding of a completely different approach?

Comment: I suggest you look at [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/).  It used to be Open Source, and you can probably find a link to their old Open Source to try it out.  It is clean, but uses objects (DTO's) which are far cleaner than hard-coded interfaces.

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately.  I don't have authority to alter the framework for communications.

Comment: I'm not saying alter service B, but your code can use whatever method you want to communicate with B, be it a hand-rolled version or a thoroughly tested version, it is up to you.  ServiceStack, will use XML out-of-the-box.  Pass it an object that contains your `id`, `latitude`, etc, and it will serialize it to XML for you.

Comment: As an aside, your question is a bit confusing, because you are saying Service B is doing both the sending and receiving...I'll assume you meant A should use the utility class. That said, I don't know if you want to add ServiceStack or not, but I agree with the suggestion to create the lat/long data as a dto and add a method to your utility class that simply serializes the dto to xml using `XmlSerializer` or one of the others if you are adventurous...same concept as what you have, but avoiding the hand-coded document construction.

Comment: Wow, I missed that error.  Thanks for pointing it out!